# Syncing folders/files on two computers w/Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, dropbox, sync, mac

I currently use Dropbox to sync some folders on two different machines. The two machines have symbolic links to the same folder inside my Dropbox folder, and it works great. Is anything like this possible with Google Drive? For some reason, I'm having trouble with symbolic links inside the Google Drive folder. I tried using hard links, but that seems problematic and on a mac it also seems more dangerous. Anyone successfully do this?

Comment: Since this is a question about the file synchronization feature of Google Drive, rather than using the web interface, this question is better suited to [su].

Answer (score 3):

One option is to **move** the directory (let's call it `alpha`) you want to Google Drive, and then make a soft (symbolic) link from its original location `beta` to `alpha`:

```
ln -s /path/to/alpha /path/to/beta
```

[Source](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/sync-any-folder-with-google-drive-skydrive-and-dropbox/).